# How to initialize std::shared_ptr with derive-class type data?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have 2 simple classes appended below:

```
class IParams
{

    ...

};

class QEParams : public IParams
{

    ...

};
```

I also have a pointer which points to IParams type:

```
std::shared_ptr<IParams> parameters;
```

I am trying to initialize it with some QEParams data, but it's not working correctly.

```
void QEExec::initialize(IParams& params)
{

    this->parameters = std::make_shared<IParams>(params);

}

...

QEParams params(-3.0, -3.0, 2.0);
QEExec exec;
exec.initialize(params);

...
```

What am i doing wrong and how to do that properly? QEExec is also a derived class, and intialize() overrides base method, that's the reason of type IParams in parameters list.

Comment: Please provide a proper [repro]. Why are you creating an instance of `QEParams`, then pass it to `initialize` as reference to the base class? This way you are loosing the information about the concrete class. You should use `std::make_shared<QEParams>(-3.0, -3.0, 2.0)` in the first place and pass that around as `shared_ptr<IParams>` (to which it can be implicitly converted).

Answer (score 0):

```
void QEExec::initialize(IParams& params)
```

So even despite you're passing an instance of `QEParams`, `initialize` sees it as `IParams`. When you create a fresh shared instance on stack, `IParams`' copy constructor is invoked.

You should either change `params` type to an actual subclass

```
void QEExec::initialize(QEParams& params)
```

or make it templated

```
template<class Subtype> void QEExec::initialize(Subtype& params) {
    parameters = std::make_shared<Subtype>(params);
```

or move allocation out of the function

```
void QEExec::initialize(std::shared_ptr<IParams> params) {
    parameters = std::move(params);
```

or add an old-fashioned `Clone` method to the interface:

```
struct IParams {
    std::shared_ptr<IParams> Clone() const = 0;
};

template<class Sub> struct ClonableParams: IParams {
    std::shared_ptr<IParams> Clone() const override {
        return std::make_shared<Sub>(static_cast<Sub>(*this));
    }
};

struct QEParams: ClonableParams<QEParams> {};
```

or etc, etc.